# spinner listner not triggered inside fragment

Tags: android, httprequest, android-spinner, android-volley

i have a spinner populated inside a fragment.
but when i press on one of the items the listener doesn't work.
i defined a spinner inside the xml file and i try to set its height width to 0 
i go thru all the internet and i steel cant make it work.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(mPageNumber==0){
        rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_worker_data_q1, container, false);
        tvr = new TextView[2];
        tvr[0] = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.responser0);
        tvr[1] = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.responser1);
        spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        lables = new ArrayList<String>(); //= db.getAllLabels();
        makeJsonObjReq();
        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

        // Drop down layout style - 
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View container,
                    int pos, long id) {
                tvr[0].setText(spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());      
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });  
    }
    else if(mPageNumber==1){        
    }
     return rootView;
}
```

if i cancel the makeObjReq() for taking the labels from my server and put some labels by hand it work. but i need to get the labels from my server. i think the problem its with the request because the rootView return before the request are done.

```
private void makeJsonObjReq() {
        showProgressDialog();
        RequestQueue queue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue();
        JsonObjectRequest myReq= new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                                                 "http://10.0.0.3/task_manager/v1/works",
                                                 null, createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                                                 createMyReqErrorListener()) {
         };
         myReq.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty("tag_json_arry") ? MyVolley.class.getSimpleName() : "tag_json_arry");
         queue.add(myReq);
     }
private Listener<JSONObject> createMyReqSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                JSONArray j = new JSONArray(response.getString("works"));
                int id;
                String name;
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(j.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    id = row.getInt("id");
                    name = row.getString("name");
                    lables.add(name);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `but when i press on one of the items the listener doesn't work`,on which item it doesn't work?It doesn't work for only one particular item and works for every other items?Is it your top most item?

Comment: I have 3 items inside and non of them triggered the listener

Comment: Please try making a `Toast` inside  `onItemSelected` and let me know if the toast works or not.Want to make sure if there an issue with `tvr[0]`.

Comment: the toast don't work.
i also put a break point inside the listener when i debugging and also it don't get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makeJsonObjReq();` is an asynchronous method, but u set the adapter after the calling this function, this time label list length will be 0 only, so either set the spinner adapter after getting the response or notify your adapter  `onResponse` method for data set changed.